# convert utf-8 string to windows-1250 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to convert utf-8 string to windows-1250 encoding. Is there any easy way in js/jquery, like `iconv()`? Maybe anybody got a chunk of code to do that....

I am writting script to convert HTML table to CSV, I need it to be Windows-1250 encoded, because Excel (at least Polish version) uses that encoding, and changing it to UTF-8 every time is pain in the ass.

The script generates data link `data:application/csv,csv_content` to save the content of generated csv file.

Comment: JavaScript works with UCS-2 (usually); why do you want to mess with encoding?

Comment: Provide more context, there's likely a completely different way to deal with whatever problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Why all those `-1` ??? I am writting script to convert HTML table to CSV, I need it to be Windows-1250 encoded, because Excel (at least Polish version) uses that encoding, and changing it to UTF-8 every time is pain in the ass.

Comment: how do you save the content ie csv file?

Comment: by `data:application/csv;` link

Comment: Have you tried adding a BOM to the result? That typically triggers correct UTF-8 behavior in Excel.

Comment: @deceze Wow... as easy as that, thank you. It helped. I can accept your answer if you'd like to, but you have to write your comment as answer in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your *actual* question: to make Excel recognize UTF-8 encoded files, add a BOM. Using a locale specific encoding is just shifting the problem around, as another Excel installation on another machine will expect another locale specific encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you could use iconv-lite to encode to Windows-1250. Adding BOM might not be enough. Especially in Excel 2003 or Excel on Mac.

Another option is to use utf16LE as described in http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/CSV+tests+of+encoding+and+column+separator?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com